# Does having hardware encoding chip help?

Tags: streaming, video-capture

I've been googling for a while now so I finally decided to ask others as well as I'm pretty darn confused.

I'm looking to be able to stream at 1080p at 60fps ( from a gaming laptop, it's more than capable, running actual game at 300fps uncapped ). I know about `ShadowPlay` and it's fairly easy to use but it's annoying how it automatically changes my stream's title and the quality is pretty bad even at best settings.

Then, I have found the `Live Gamer Extreme` which has 1080p at 60fps recording and hdmi passthrough, but it doesn't have h.264 encoding chip so I'm receiving RAW data in `OBS` ( there are cards that have hardware encoding chips already but those don't do 60fps as far as I can see )

So, does having a h.264 encoding chip help in any way ? 
Because I'd like doing the whole thing on one laptop and not having to use two laptops one for gaming and one for encoding would be great.

In `OBS's Encoding` tab I can't find any option like `No encoding needed` since the signal is already encoded, so, should I look anymore for 60fps w/ encoding chip or should I go with this game capturing card and use the other laptop for encoding.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hardware encoder will produce video with less CPU usage. However, it will require a higher bitrate to achieve the same quality image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that specific device, but I can answer a resounding YES to the question of "does having a dedicated h264 encoding chip help?". With a proper hardware device you can either let it run totally solo (preconfigured with settings and then just connected to the network) or you can connect it to your laptop to command and control it, but it will not use any of your machine's cpu for encoding.

Comment: While this is true, video quality is ALWAYS be worse at a given bitrate using a hardware encoder than a good software implementation such as x264

Comment: What do you mean? Let's say the hardware encoder is using x264, if you compared that to a software implementation of x264 at the same bitrate, the quality should be identical.

I often use both hardware and software based h264 encoders, and if I use the same setup, the quality is exactly the same for me.

Comment: This is false. first, there is no such thing as hardware x264. x264 is the name of a specific implementation of an h264 encoder. Some encoders can produce better quality than others at a fixed bitrate. In fact x264 can produces better/worse than itself by changing the preset and trading more CPU time for extra quality. At high bitrates the difference may not be noticeable. But a low bitrates, it is very obvious.

Comment: I don't want to argue with you, this isn't helping the thread. The question asked was a specific question: He wants to use a single machine to game at very high qualities, while simultaneously streaming out a 1080p 60fps live feed. A hardware based encoder is pretty much the only way I can see to make this happen with one laptop, would you agree? Bringing in raw video and encoding it in software (even with the best ever x264 config in the world) will crush his cpu and leave nothing for the game.

Comment: You are correct here. What you are missing is that he want to send high quality video at a low bitrate. It is obvious that the OP is streaming to Twitch. Twitch has a soft cap of 3.5Mbps. 1080@60 3.5Mbps will look terrible on a hardware encoder. It may be passable using x264. So, yes, hardware will help the CPU/game, but it will hurt the video stream.

Comment: Agreed on that quality assessment. I know this isn't what he asked, but if it is Twitch, then forget the 1080@60 ... Just do a 720 @ 1.5m, and use software. His machine should be able to handle the game and the video encode no problem, and without having to purchase and use a separate dedicated hardware encoder.